# Multiple meshes or multiple objects in a single mesh?

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh

I'm trying to load multiple objects into a vbo in opengl. If I want to be able to move these objects independently should I use a mesh for each object or should I load all the objects to a single mesh?

Also in my code I have...

> loc1 = glGetAttribLocation(shaderP, "vertex_position");

Now I understand that this gets the vertex positions in my current program but if I want to load another object I load the mesh and then how can I get the vertex positions again but for only that mesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, as often, "it depends". Having one "mesh" (i.e. one buffer) per object is arguably "cleaner" but it is also likely slower. One buffer per object will make you bind a different buffer much more often. Tiny vertex buffer objects (a few dozen vertices) are as bad as huge ones (gigabytes of data). You should try to find a "reasonable" thing in between

The as of version 3.2 readily available `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` (also exists as instanced version) will allow you to seamlessly draw several objects or pieces from one buffer without having to fiddle with renumbering indices, and without having to switch buffers.

You should preferrably (presuming OpenGL 3.3 availability) not use `glGetAttribLocation` at all, but [assign the attribute to a location](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Shader#Inputs) using the layout specifier. That way you **know** the location, you don't need to ask every time, and you don't have to worry that "weird, unexpected stuff" might happen.
If you can't do it in the shader, use `glBindAttribLocation` (available since version 2.0) instead. It is somewhat less comfortable, but does the same thing. You get to **decide** the location instead of asking for it and worrying that the compiler hopefully didn't change the order for two different shaders.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally cleaner if you use different buffers for different objects.

According to:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml
This will only returned the pointer to the location of the data. You use this to bind you vertex info to the program. When you render your other object you will bind to the vbo that stores the other vertices.

Comment: Ok but should I use one mesh for all my objects or multiple meshes?

Comment: It's cleaner if you use multiple meshes.